# How to choose DC resistance parameter of a USB 2.0 common mode choke?

Tags: usb, resistance, emc, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

How do i know whether i have to choose a bigger sized common mode choke with lower DC resistance for USB 2.0 D+/D- lines or using a smaller one with higher DC resistance is also just ok?

In fact there are several USB 2.0 common mode chokes (Common mode impedance: 90Ohm @ 100MHz) on the market with different DC resistances roughly ranging from 100mOhm up to 5Ohm.

Any clarification on how to choose an adequate (or low enough) DC resistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers impedance is generally lower than the USB cable impedance giving some tolerance to DCR for the CM choke.

But a higher impedance CM choke like 500 Ohms with 5 Ohms DCR will greatly improve CMRR and should not interfere much with signal integrity yet give better immunity. This should improve signal damping as well but may limit BW on the fastest USB3.

I’d have to look at the details and your specs for the above.

Depending on your USB speeds and interference, 270 Ohms @ 100 MHz 0.5 Ohm DCR may be adequate. But > 500 Ohms @ 5 DCR will be better if SRF is beyond your BW.

Comment: Ok so eventually a driver has, say only 85Ohm output impedance which could form together with any series impedance due to design (CMC, trace resistance,..) again a impedance value closer to 90Ohm, right? Your answer leads me to another question: Why do common mode chokes intended for USB 2.0 applications always have a common mode impedance of 90Ohms @ 100Mhz?  I understand USB has a differential impedance of 90Ohms. But you have mentioned CM chokes with higher common mode impedance for same application...

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Intel](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.169.6351&rep=rep1&type=pdf)'s recommendation. Common-mode chokes degrade the signal but may solve an EMI problem.

> Finding a common mode choke that meets the designer’s needs is a two-step process.
>
> 1. A part must be chosen with the impedance value that provides the required noise attenuation. This is a function of the electrical and
>    mechanical characteristics of the part chosen, and the frequency and
>    strength of the noise present on the USB traces that the designer is
>    trying to suppress.
> 2. Once the designer has a part that gives passing EMI results, the second step is to test the effect this part has on signal quality.
>    Higher impedance common mode chokes generally have a greater damaging
>    effect on signal quality, so be careful about increasing the impedance
>    without doing thorough testing. Thorough testing means that the signal
>    quality must be checked for Low speed, Full speed and High speed USB
>    operation.

I don't think the DCR of the USB signal lines is a big deal.

[image]